# No Protection by Signature on Specific Manifest Entry in Building an Android Application

Tags: java, android, build, android-build

I'm trying to sign an APK for publishing on the Play Store that was originally built with Cordova and Ionic. Now, after going through the steps:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore release-key.jks android-release-unsigned.apk xxxxxx
zipalign -v 4 android-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk
apksigner verify HelloWorld.apk
```

I then get the error when I verify using apksigner as follows:

```
WARNING: META-INF/services/com.google.protobuf.GeneratedExtensionRegistryLoader
not protected by signature. Unauthorized modifications to this JAR entry will no
t be detected. Delete or move the entry outside of META-INF/.
```

Will this matter at all? How could I resolve this problem? Is there anything I've done wrong in my build?

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the APK
2. Delete every file inside META-INF/
3. Zip the entire contents as .apk
4. Sign the above APK now without any error.

Comment: Where the directory of META-INF/ ? I am facing this issue :( Need to publish asap

Comment: Once you extract the apk using any zip utility (e.g: 7-Zip in Windows) to a folder, you will find the META-INF folder inside the unzipped folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just obfuscate META-INF/* with proguard, dexguard or similar tool